Is it appropriate to use R² on filtering data?
At work, someone has built a dashboard to identify individuals likely to have higher value of the output variable. The approach involves fitting a OLS and measuring the R² value. They attempt to achieve a high R² by adjusting the underlying data with filters, such as excluding individuals with fewer/greater than X of a different covariate until the R² value is high.
I have concerns about the appropriateness and validity of this method. Specifically, I wonder if this approach might be misleading or statistically inappropriate. My statistics knowledge is not great, so i was hoping for a proper reason I can provide to why it is inappropriate and alternative methods that would make more sense. Or let me know if i'm incorrect and this method is sufficient.
thanks

I assume the R2 is then used to argue about how well the algorithm can predict this outcome value. Interpreting the coefficients of an OLS is always at least problematic.
If you apply this filtering on the whole dataset, the resulting number is going to be biased. For example, you can filter out the hard examples and get a good R2. It is not going to be representative of the performance on the whole dataset.
After splitting train- test- and validation set, there are some situations where this filtering might be ok. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation.
Roughly, if you use the R2 on the test set, while filtering only the training set, the R2 will give you an estimate that is an approximation of the "true performance". It can be beneficial to remove some samples from training, because they have an outsized effect on the algorithm, and get a better fit for it. However, if you try out many different configurations and pick the best, this is some variant of https://xkcd.com/882/.
